# Connecting C# with SQL Server Database in a Local Area Network (LAN)

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, networking

I have created a C# application that I want to run on a Local Area Network, so that different PCs can install my application and access the database stored on Server PC.
Now the point is that i am really a rookie when it comes to Network connectivity. Right now I use this code to connect to my database:

```
public SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost; Initial Catalog= my_db; Integrated Security= True");
```

Can you guys help me with this? 
Thanks in Advance.

P.S. Do i have to install SQL Server Management Studio in Server PC?

Comment: Do you have problems using that connection string? If yes please explain. No Sql Server Management Studio is not required for a Net Application to connect to a Sql Server database

Comment: I have not tried anything yet, before I do anything i have to be sure not to screw up my workplace LAN. Therefore, before deploying my software there, I am asking for expert opinion here.

Comment: I suggest you read some tutorials first. If you have specific problems, you can ask again here. This question is a bit too generic to be answered.

Comment: Your first decision is which security are you going to use?  Integrated (the user they logon to their PC with) or SQL Security?  If you use Integrated the easiest way is to add all your users to a group(s) and allow that group the required access to the database.  If SQL then create the logons on the SQL server, give them the required access and update your connection string accordingly.

Comment: @MuhKuh I agree with you, but the problem is I can't find any specific tutorial which can help me with this problem. Neither can I find any videos.

Comment: Well... I think I asked a really dumb question :P But thanks for your help anyways guys.. I really appreciate it

Comment: This does help with your specific problem.  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C  And this http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Answer (score 1):

Try to use with Server IP address

```
string connectionString = "SERVER=123.123.1.12;" + "UID=xxxxxxx;" + "PWD=xxxxxxx;" + "DATABASE=xxxxxx;" + "Encrypt=FALSE;";
```

Here the IP Address is just for Demo only.Use your own.I'm currently have this, and works 100% fine.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously with your current connection string your clients will be trying to connect to their own computers. You should use something like `"Server=yourServerAddress;Database=yourDataBase;User Id=username;
Password=password;"` instead.

Comment: So instead of "Data Source", i have to write "Server" and write the path of the server and the directory where I store my .mdi file?

Comment: "Server" is just the address of your server. "192.168.1.111", for example. "Database" is the name of the database. "my_db", for example. You don't need to specify the path to the actual database files, server knows where they are.

Answer (score 0):

```
"Server=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DBName;User ID=sa;Password=Pass;"
```

here ServerName you find in your SQl server->Object Explorer where you find IP address or name ,Initial Catalog is your DB name